# I'm trying to set the cookie to my site to button on click action ,it is working on when user logged in .When user logged out it's not working

Tags: jquery

```
function cookiebasedredirect() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).on('click', '#organisation', function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      jQuery.cookie("site_changer", "organisation", { expires: 1 });
      window.location.href = window.location.href;
    });

    jQuery(document).on('click', '#young-professional', function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      jQuery.cookie("site_changer", "young-professional", { expires: 1 });
      window.location.href = window.location.href;
    });
  </script>
<?php

 }
 add_action("wp_head", "cookiebasedredirect");
```

Comment: Empty browser and caching plugin's caches.

Comment: Cleared but still not working ...

Answer (score 2):

Your script uses jQuery so you should make sure that:

- jQuery is enqueued on your site (it may be for logged-in users, especially admins, but not necessarily for logged-out users)
- your script is added with jQuery as a dependency so jQuery is available when your script runs

I would use [`wp_add_inline_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_script/) for this, like so:

```
function wpse310935_cookiebasedredirect() {
    ob_start();
    ?>
    jQuery(document).on('click', '#organisation', function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      jQuery.cookie("site_changer", "organisation", { expires: 1 });
      window.location.href = window.location.href;
    });

    jQuery(document).on('click', '#young-professional', function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      jQuery.cookie("site_changer", "young-professional", { expires: 1 });
      window.location.href = window.location.href;
    });
    <?php
    $my_js = ob_get_clean();
    if( ! wp_script_is( 'jquery', 'enqueued' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    }
    wp_add_inline_script( 'jquery', $my_js );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse310935_cookiebasedredirect' );
```

Comment: thanks for the support its working, now i am facing when click on inner pages it will have to change but it doesn't  .please have a look 
https://elevateyp.com/

Comment: click on organisation then click inner pages .